# what is the name of the banner that is fixed on the bottom of a webpage

Tags: ads, banner

There are many types of banners, like standard, popup, popunder, popinto (or hover banner), etc..

But what is the name of the banner, that is very similiar to a popinto (hover banner), but instead to be on center of the webpage, is shown fixed on bottom of a webpage?

Usually to close this kind of banners there is a "close" text or icon.

i call "bottom banner" but i'm not sure that is the real name ;)